# Restart pandas timeseries dataset timestamp from 0

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, time-series

I am working with python and pandas.

I have some timeseries data in this format in a dataframe:

```
    timeStampStart          Measurement
0   2019-02-26 22:47:39.914 810
1   2019-02-26 22:47:40.747 854
2   2019-02-26 22:47:40.743 862
```

I have several other datasets in this way. Basically I ran an experiment which collects results over time, collecting `timeStampStart` and a value.

Now I want to offset all my data such that the first result starts from 0000-00-00 00:00:00 and the ones that follow are just the difference - the timestamp restarts from time 0.

```
    timeStampStart          Measurement
0   0000-00-00 00:00:00.000 810
1   0000-00-00 00:00:00.834 854
2   0000-00-00 00:00:00.830 862
```

Note: timeStampStart type is `pandas._libs.tslib.Timestamp`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need [timedeltas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timedeltas.html) by subtract by first value of `timeStampStart` column, because datetimes with `00:00:00` not exist:

```
df['td'] = df['timeStampStart'].sub(df['timeStampStart'].iat[0])
print (df)
           timeStampStart  Measurement              td
0 2019-02-26 22:47:39.914          810        00:00:00
1 2019-02-26 22:47:40.747          854 00:00:00.833000
2 2019-02-26 22:47:40.743          862 00:00:00.829000

print (df.dtypes)
timeStampStart     datetime64[ns]
Measurement                 int64
td                timedelta64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Comment: Since this is correct, there is no valid explanation.

Comment: @AndyHayden - It is better?

Comment: @AndyHayden - Thank you.